# curled brackets in .format

Tags: python, string, format

I want to print the following

```
\printCodeFromFile[5]{7}{myfile.tex}
```

which I construct with the following code

```
outputStr = "\\printCodeFromFile[{startline}]{{endline}}{{name}}".format(startline=lineStart, endline=lineEnd, name=filename)
```

That unfortunately comes out as

```
 \printCodeFromFile[5]{endline}{name}
```

So how would I escape or insert the curled brackets such that they are printed and the variable is inserted ? I could not find any hint in the docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Double the curly braces that you want to keep:

```
outputStr = "\\printCodeFromFile[{startline}{{{endline}}}{{{name}}}]".format(startline=lineStart, endline=lineEnd, name=filename)
```

Now you have doubled braces (`{{` and `}}`) surrounding the replacement pattern (`{endline}` and `{name}`).